# GitLab Pipeline fails connecting to Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, devops

When I execute the pipeline job as the video shows it fails and give a message:

**ERROR: Preparation failed: error connecting to Kubernetes: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided**

Is this intended? have i missed any configuration?

the kubernetes is configured for my runner and the project i am working on and i haven't seen any configuration to config

Comment: This sounds like a question for GitLab tech support.

Comment: Did you register the runner on the master node?

Comment: My runner does this too - but only about a 10th of the times. It runs find after I retry.

Comment: @JasonPrawn I am seeing the same exact thing! Did you have it resolved?

Comment: @Syed Raza Did you have it resolved? Please share your solution

Comment: I had to rename the runner, and it solved for me. Thanks.