# ERROR: Preparation failed: getting Kubernetes config: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Hey guys this is blocking my flow! I have my gitlab runner installed on my Windows machine.

I registered a runner with a kubernetes executor. It previously used to work, but not any more.

I have a kubernetes cluster (the one provided by docker desktop) and the log of my jobs show this error:

```
ERROR: Preparation failed: getting Kubernetes config: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided
```

I have checked a few other resources regarding this issue, such as: [this gitlab runner issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4902) , [this other gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1759) and this [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502241/gitlab-pipeline-fails-connecting-to-kubernetes) but no solution has worked.

The runner on my Runners setting is Running (Green)

The `config.toml` file looks correct:

```
concurrent = 5
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "kubernetes runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "My_Token"
  executor = "kubernetes"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.kubernetes]
    host = ""
    bearer_token_overwrite_allowed = false
    image = ""
    namespace = ""
    namespace_overwrite_allowed = ""
    privileged = false
    service_account_overwrite_allowed = ""
    pod_annotations_overwrite_allowed = ""
    [runners.kubernetes.affinity]
    [runners.kubernetes.pod_security_context]
    [runners.kubernetes.volumes]
    [runners.kubernetes.dns_config]
```

and the config file is definitely in my home directory `$HOME/.kube`

I'm not sure how things work on windows, maybe the code is not able configured to find this path in windows? The thing is, it used to work before!

Also running:

```
kubectl get pods
```

returns results

Any one knows what might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem.

What I found is that when you run `kubectl` you run it with root or some user.
For the `gitlab-runner` however there is a seperate user.

Running `kubectl` works because there is a Kubernetes config dir for this user `/home/<kubectl-user>/.kube`.
It doesn't work for your gitlab runner since there is no config dir for the user.

Copying `/home/<kubectl-user>/.kube/` into `/home/<gitlab-runner-user>/` should solve your issue